# What binoculars are used that target enemies in bf4 and how to get it?

Tags: battlefield-4

When I played bf4 solo mode I noticed that there are binoculars that target enemies. How can I get this in multiplayer mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. To target enemies you have to aim at them and press the <kbd>Q</kbd> key. It will show a red triangle above them.

If an enemy is in the vehicle, it will show a small red pic of that vehicle. Like that you and your teammates will see where the enemies are.

Just don't forget, that it lasts only a few seconds and not constantly like in campaign

Comment: Should make sure what version he is playing before saying what button to use, just a thought

Comment: i am using the latest pc version. no clue what version it is though

Answer (score 8):

They are not available in multiplayer. The closest thing you could get is the PLD for Recon, which allows you to laser paint vehicles.

*Edited for clarity, thanks Dupree3*
It's also worth noting that it uses infrared vision, making spotting easier.

Comment: This is what he is looking for. It is in infrared so it is easy to spot people. When using them just look for enemies and just use the usual spotting button. It is the same concept as a normal spot, but it just makes it easier to see them.

Comment: @Dupree3 Thanks, I'll update my answer :) I didn't know if it was IRNV or FLIR

Comment: Yeah its one of the first things you get in the recon class if not already have it right off the bat. Your welcome!